# Laravel rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I'm trying to make htaccess rewrite work on apache2 ubuntu 17.04 however it won't work. what i'm trying to do is access the route with localhost/anyroute but the only way to access it is localhost/PROJECTNAME/public/anyroute. localhost/ANYROUTE works on windows but apache will return "The requested url not found" on ubuntu and i have no idea why.. here are my confs file
.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

my vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/public/
<Directory /var/www/html/test/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

so bottom line is that localhost/anyroute won't work but localhost/project/public/anyroute will work. i have pretty much tried everything :/

Comment: first, confirm rewrite mod is enable or not. if not show my answer.

Comment: @SujalPatel its enabled when i do sudeo a2enmod rewrite it says module is already enabled

Comment: Try to below step to edit default config file.

Comment: @Sujalpatel nope not working

Answer (score 5):

**Enabling mod_rewrite**

Now, we need to activate mod_rewrite.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already in effect. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

We will need to set up and secure a few more settings before we can begin.

First, allow changes in the .htaccess file. Open the default Apache configuration file using nano or your favorite text editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Inside that file, you will find the  block on line 1. Inside of that block, add the following block:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Your file should now match the following. Make sure that all blocks are properly indented.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>

        . . .

    </Directory>

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now, create the .htaccess file.

For Detail Follow Below Reference Link :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04